# React - Cleanest way to re-render component on array update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, use-effect

I'm new using react hooks and i was struggling with the useEffect hook due to the following:

I have a simple comment board to post comments and below a list of the comments posted, and i want every time a new comment is made the component reloads to show it.

[image]

These commments are got it from an API in the useEffect first parameter, the problem is the second parameter (dependecies array), if i don't put this parameter causes an infinite loop, if i put an empty array it avoids the infinite loop but instead my component doesn't render new comments posted, and if i put the variable state "comments" causes an infinite loop too. So navigating in the internet i found "the solution" that is simply as add another variable state to pass it to the dependencies array and is modified when i call the function "makecomponent" and this way it refreshs the state forcing my component to re render:

```js
export const ForumApp = () => {
    const [comment, setComment] = useState("")
    const [comments, setComments] = useState([])
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
 
    useEffect(() => {
        const getComments = async () => {
            try {
                const query = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/comments")
                setComments(query.data.comments)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
        getComments()
    }, [count])

    const handleEnter = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
        if (e.key === ENTER && !e.shiftKey) {
            e.preventDefault();
            makeComment();
        }
    };

    const makeComment = async () => {
        try {
            await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/comments/create", {
                time: "1:29",
                content: comment,
            })

            alert("Comment posted!")
            setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1)
            setComment("")
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="forum-app">
            <div className="comment-board">
                <h1>Post your comment</h1>
                <textarea
                    placeholder="Write something to us"
                    onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}
                    onKeyDown={handleEnter}
                    value={comment}
                ></textarea>
                <br />
                <button onClick={makeComment}>Comment</button>
            </div>
            <ol>
                {
                    comments.map(({_id, content}) => (
                        <CommentItem key={_id} content={content}/>
                    ))
                }
            </ol>
        </div>
    )
}
```

So basically my question is: is this the "correct" way to do it or does exist another cleaner way without declare another variable and only doing it with what i have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other cleaner way is likely to use redux & redux-thunk to dispatch an action to do the asynchronous fetching. When the data is fetched and the redux store is updated then the connected components rerender with the latest state from the store.

This is a lot of new moving parts to add to an app if it isn't already using redux. The important aspect here is the necessary additional "flag" to trigger another data fetch.

I think a tweak I'd recommend for your code to make it a bit more straight forward is to actually define a `fetchData` state that is toggled on and off depending on the status of fetching data. This allows you to also display any "loading" state while the data is being fetched.

```
export const ForumApp = () => {
    const [comment, setComment] = useState("")
    const [comments, setComments] = useState([])
    const [fetchComments, setFetchComments] = useState(true) // <-- for initial mount call
 
    useEffect(() => {
        const getComments = async () => {
            try {
                const query = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/comments")
                setComments(query.data.comments)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } finally {
              setFetchComments(false); // <-- signify fetching complete
            }
        }

        fetchComments && getComments(); // <-- fetch comments if true
    }, [fetchComments])

    const handleEnter = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
        if (e.key === ENTER && !e.shiftKey) {
            e.preventDefault();
            makeComment();
        }
    };

    const makeComment = async () => {
        try {
            await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/comments/create", {
                time: "1:29",
                content: comment,
            })

            alert("Comment posted!")
            setFetchComments(true); // <-- signify start fetching
            setComment("")
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="forum-app">
            <div className="comment-board">
                <h1>Post your comment</h1>
                <textarea
                    placeholder="Write something to us"
                    onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}
                    onKeyDown={handleEnter}
                    value={comment}
                ></textarea>
                <br />
                <button onClick={makeComment}>Comment</button>
            </div>
            <ol>
                {
                    fetchComments 
                      ? "...fetching comments" // <-- loading state
                      : comments.map(({_id, content}) => (
                        <CommentItem key={_id} content={content}/>
                    ))
                }
            </ol>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: So the cleanest way to do it is to use redux? or at least is what you recommend?
I had been avoiding it but i guess it's time to learn it.
Thanks for the code, for the moment is what i was lookin' for.

Comment: @AbrahamArreola I suppose in this case "clean" is a bit subjective. Personally I think either could be considered "clean". Using the way you had and in my answer it is clean in the sense that all the logic is contained in a single unit, is easy to read, and is a simple common pattern. Redux is a clean event driven pattern which allows you to abstract away and modularize common functions such as fetching data asynchronously and using a common app state. It sort of all depends on your app's needs and requirements. Cheers and good luck.

Comment: @Draw Reese Hello again, currently i learned and implemented redux to my app, but now i have a similar question: do i need also an aditional flag to trigger the fetch or can i achieve this with what i have?
I tried passing the dispatch in the depency array but it didn't work.
Cheers!

Comment: @AbrahamArreola If you've implemented redux into your app then the pattern here is to use [asynchronous actions](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic) via a middleware (like redux-thunk). The fetch logic is moved to the asynchronous action. You wouldn't need use any extra flags to trigger the action as you can directly dispatch an asynchronous action (from a button click for example) to your store. If you need more assistance feel free to ask another question here on SO and (at) me here with a link to it, you'll at least possibly get more eyes on it more quickly.

Comment: i've implemented async actions with redux-thunk too and i know i can dispatch any action to the store, but with this i want to achieve the same thing i asked in this post: list all comments when component displays and update the list when a new comment is made. I actually did it putting the dispatch in the useEffect function but the component doesn't re render when i put a new comment. And now my question is, do i still needing a flag to control the data fetch or can i achieve this only with the redux methods?

Comment: @AbrahamArreola IMO it should all be handled in redux. Presumably your async action should fetch the data and dispatch an action to update the store. If your component is connected to the store correctly it'll rerender and display the updated state.

Comment: acutely it not good way to use redux to update all component in the react application barbecue when u update all Dom with your redux state. and render all component each time you update a little state in your redxu when in reducer use return {...state , key : new-value} you get re-render  all of your application and it's have performance issue. in react and in regular component like class components and functional component if you pass 1 to state that's already have 1 your component get re render and it's don't compare 1 vs 1 .

Comment: also if you use pure component in your application and use redux state to render  elements in that's component you pass compare of pure component so for use pure component you have to pass your redux state into component by props then pure component can prevent from unnecessary re-render

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent

Comment: @mahdiashori I don't understand your comments much or why they are even relevant, redux and asynchronous actions were only mentioned as a method of achieving code that was more clean. Redux is used for state management, and asynchronous actions in the case of thunks. Only subscribed components rerender, not the entire app. What specific performance issue/issues are you referring to? The rest of your comment about pure components is a bit incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

### i prefer to user and function as generator and give state as parameters then return my map component to make readable code

---

by this way you don't need to understand JSX to understand logic of code and more flexible for debug i think

```
export const ForumApp = () => {
const [comment, setComment] = useState("")
const [comments, setComments] = useState([])
const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

useEffect(() => {
    const getComments = async () => {
        try {
            const query = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/comments")
            setComments(query.data.comments)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    getComments()
}, [count])

const handleEnter = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (e.key === ENTER && !e.shiftKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
        makeComment();
    }
};

const makeComment = async () => {
    try {
        await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/comments/create", {
            time: "1:29",
            content: comment,
        })

        alert("Comment posted!")
        setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1)
        setComment("")
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
};
const commentGenerator = (data) => (data.map(({ _id, content }) => <CommentItem key={_id} content={content} />))

return (
    <div className="forum-app">
        <div className="comment-board">
            <h1>Post your comment</h1>
            <textarea
                placeholder="Write something to us"
                onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}
                onKeyDown={handleEnter}
                value={comment}
            ></textarea>
            <br />
            <button onClick={makeComment}>Comment</button>
        </div>
        <ol>
            {commentGenerator(comments)}
        </ol>
    </div>
)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

so if you want to ad loading for it and even better you want have some lazy load component for lazy load to get better performance at loading page you can use react lazy and suspense to fetch data and load comment component when you data fetch successfully by this approach you don't any state or variable and also you can loading component and it's automatically Handel changing state of loading and load list of component.

```
import { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';

const CommentItem = lazy(() => import('./CommentItem'));

export const ForumApp = () => {

const getComments = async () => {
    try {
        const query = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/comments")
        return query.data.comments.map((commentItem) => <CommentItem {...commentItem} />)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return []
    }
}


return (
    <div className="forum-app">
        <div className="comment-board">
            <h1>Post your comment</h1>
            <textarea
                placeholder="Write something to us"
                onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}
                onKeyDown={handleEnter}
                value={comment}
            ></textarea>
            <br />
            <button onClick={makeComment}>Comment</button>
        </div>
        <ol>
            <Suspense fallback={<span> loading comments...</span>}>
                {getComments()}
            </Suspense>
        </ol>
    </div>
)
}
```